# How to create multiple callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the fadeIn in 3 seconds, but this not work in the part function color().
What it is the best way to do this?

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow", function(){
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
       color();
    });

   function color(){
    $("p").css('color','red').fadeIn('3000');
    color2();
  }

   function color2(){
    $("p").animate({'margin-top':'100px'});
   }
});
```

Comment: its better to cache ('p') in variable if you will use it more than once.

Comment: also you margin top should be written in camel case marginTop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
    var p = $('p');

$('button').on('click', function () {

    p.each(function() {

        $(this).hide('slow', function () {

            $(this).css('color', 'red').fadeIn('slow', function () {

                $(this).animate({
                    marginTop: '100px'

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't code them in a function?

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow", function(){
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
        $("p").css('color','red').fadeIn('3000');
        $("p").animate({'margin-top':'100px'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that fadeIn accepts integer input, not a string of a number. Remove the quotes from its argument.

$("p").css('color','red').fadeIn(3000);

Strings provided as parameters to fadeIn should be one of the predefined values, such as "slow"

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/